# Preferred way to start a hadoop datanode

Tags: hadoop

Functionally, I was wondering whether there is a difference between starting a hadoop namenode with the command:

```
$HADOOP_HOME/sbin/hadoop-daemons.sh --config $HADOOP_CONF_DIR --script hdfs start datanode
```

and:

```
hdfs datanode
```

The first command gives me an error stating that the datanode cannot ssh into itself(this is running on a docker container), while the second command seems to run without that issue. The official hadoop documentation for this version, (2.9.1) doesn't mention "hdfs datanode" as a way to start a datanode.

Comment: I think the preferred way is `start-dfs.sh` (which may call one of those other ways)

Comment: Okay, but for an individualy datanode, is hdfs datanode functionally any different?

Comment: It directly calls the Java class. It doesn't allow configuration overrides. https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs/src/main/bin/hdfs#L95

Comment: I think you haven't established a connection of your datanode with localhost. Try passwordless ssh localhost connection on datanode and then go with the first command. It should run

Comment: @cricket_007, by configuration overrides, do you mean the user configurable .xml files?

Comment: I mean from `hadoop-daemons.sh --config`, you can pass different directories rather than `HADOOP_CONF_DIR`. Not sure why you would do that, but it's possible.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you very much !